# Converting PL/SQL procedures to Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, plsql

```
BEGIN
   open v_refcur for
       SELECT A.LGCY_LNDR_NO
            , A.LGCY_LNDR_BR_NO
            , A.LNDR_NM
            , B.ADDR_LINE1_TXT
            , B.ADDR_LINE2_TXT
            , B.CITY_NM
            , B.ST_CD
            , B.POSTAL_CD
            , C.FAX_NO
        FROM LNDR_CUST_XREF A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LNDR_CUST_ADDR B
        ON A.LNDR_ID = B.LNDR_ID
        AND B.ADDR_TYP_CD = 'MAIL'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LNDR_CUST_ADDR C
        ON A.LNDR_ID = C.LNDR_ID
        AND C.ADDR_TYP_CD = 'SITE'
        WHERE A.LGCY_LNDR_NO = LNDR_NO
        AND A.LGCY_LNDR_BR_NO = BRN_NO
        AND A.TA_CUST_FLG = 'Y';
   SQL_CD := SWV_SQLCODE;
END;
```

What will be the line by line conversion of this above code? I dont have the databases in-hand, so what would be the most appropriate gist of the PL/SQL code in Pyspark?

Comment: You can use ```spark.sql('<SQL code>')``` and run the sql script without having to rewrite it in pyspark.

Comment: Using spark.sql('<SQL code>') is not what I intend to do, so it would be much better if you could answer as required.

Comment: It appears that you've understood the purpose of stackoevrflow incorrectly. The questions are not meant to be a tool for getting other people to do your homework. What you're asking for is not a technical question; it's a request to do your job!

Comment: My comment came out a different way, sorry about that. And thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this statement can be re-written something like below -

```
df = (df_LNDR_CUST_XREF.alias('A')
      .df_LNDR_CUST_ADDR.alias('B'), ((A.LNDR_ID == B.LNDR_ID) & (B.ADDR_TYP_CD == 'MAIL'), "left")
      .df_LNDR_CUST_ADDR.alias('C'), ((A.LNDR_ID == C.LNDR_ID) & (C.ADDR_TYP_CD == 'SITE'), "left")
      .where ((A.LGCY_LNDR_NO == LNDR_NO) & (A.LGCY_LNDR_BR_NO == BRN_NO) & (A.TA_CUST_FLG == 'Y'))
      .select (F.col("A.LGCY_LNDR_NO")
            , F.col("A.LGCY_LNDR_BR_NO")
            , F.col("A.LNDR_NM")
            , F.col("B.ADDR_LINE1_TXT")
            , F.col("B.ADDR_LINE2_TXT")
            , F.col("B.CITY_NM")
            , F.col("B.ST_CD")
            , F.col("B.POSTAL_CD")
            , F.col("C.FAX_NO"))
     )
```

I havent tested it though.

Comment: i think you are commenting in the wrong place. Did you get a chance to work with the answer I provided

Comment: Yes, worked with your answer. It is quite appropriate, and yes I have commented in the wrong place.